# Symfony 4 : An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar

Tags: php, symfony

I work on CentOS.

I've followed the tutorials :

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html

As I use Apache, I've followed this page too :

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

I made a default controller and a default template. With this controller (/) I get the the following error (within the debug toolbar):

```
An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar. Open the web profiler.
```

When I click on the link : "Open the web profiler", I can see the Apache response :

```
Not Found
The requested URL /_profiler/177403 was not found on this server.
```

In the chrome inspector, I can see :
GET http://172.31.18.7/_wdt/177403 404 (Not Found)

Here's the interesting part of my composer.json :

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.35",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.6",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.4",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^1.1",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^4.1",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^4.0"
    },
```

my httpd.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/elora/public
ServerName eloradev
ServerAlias www.elora.dev
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory "elora/public">
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>

<Directory elora>
    Options FollowSymlinks
</Directory>    

ErrorLog /var/apache/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/apache/logs/access.log combined  

</VirtualHost>
```

And my .htaccess :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And, to finish, my /lucky/number (https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html) raises the apache message :

```
Not Found
The requested URL /lucky/number was not found on this server.
```

It looks like the routing component does'nt work.

The router rules (debug:router) :

```
-------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------
Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path
-------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------- 
  app_homepage               ANY      ANY      ANY    /
  app_lucky                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /lucky
  app_lucky_number           ANY      ANY      ANY    /lucky/number
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler_open_file        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------
```

I've manually created the directory /_wdt, in case, but it did'nt change anything.

I've checked errors with debug:event-dispatcher, nothing special.

I've noticed that the cache for the profiler is in that directory : var/cache/dev/profiler/03/74/ and is named 177403

One more thing, I've ran composer with the 'root' user. And I've used chown to change the owner of my project.

Here's a part of my file .env :

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
```

Comment: Can you check if you closed he body and html tags ?

Comment: I see this now and again. To fix it I delete everything under `var\cache` and `\var\session` restart Apache and then warmup the cache again, or just run the site and let the cache get rebuilt. Takes a minute longer but solves the issue

Comment: I didn't do any change to base.html.twig, so the tags are OK.
I've forgot to say that I made a default controller and a default template. That's how I got the message "An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar"

Comment: I've cleared the cache so many times ... I've restarted Apache too.
Nothing new.

Comment: Chexk your routing rules in `routing-dev.yml` and see if you have any rules for the debugger.

Comment: Try to run `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` to check errors

Comment: Did you try the URL `http://www.elora.dev/index.php/_wdt/` ? I had a similar problem because the URL rewriting was wrong.

Comment: GREAT JOB ! I think it's my problem.
The url /index.php/lucky/number works

Thank you !

Answer (score 81):

I think this is require htaccess or mod_rewrite

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

- Configuring a Web Server

  https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue for me running the symfony app in a vagrant box for development.

Comment: In my case i wanted to work with or without an .htaccess file, so ended up with a different vhost configuration, for more information: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/793/how-to-configure-a-virtualhost-in-xampp-3-3-2-for-a-symfony-4-project

Comment: @DennisdeBest Unfortunately this didn't work running a symfony app in a laravel homestead :/

Answer (score 13):

just add :

FallbackResource /index.php

in your directory setting

```html
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/Your_public_symfony_directory">
            ....
            FallbackResource /index.php
            ....
    </Directory>
```

for more documentation [click here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

Comment: Thank you, this worked with Laragon (Apache 2.4 + PHP 7.2).

Answer (score 13):

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack

Do you want to execute this recipe?
    [y] Yes
    [n] No
    [a] Yes for all packages, only for the current installation session
    [p] Yes permanently, never ask again for this project
    (defaults to n): y
```

*Host File:*

```
127.0.0.1 symfony01.com
127.0.0.1 www.symfony01.com
```

*httpd-vhosts.conf :*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony01.com
    ServerAlias www.symfony01.com   
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/symfony01/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/symfony01/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about apache-pack

Answer (score 10):

If you are using symfony  **v5.***
go to `your_project_root > public` create a new file named `.htaccess`
Just paste the code:

---

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

if you need more information you can visit [here](https://blog.cleiver.me/symfony-4-an-error-occurred-while-loading-the-web-debug-toolbar-ck1ckgs88001mjus1xa554jov)

Comment: I was working on a Symfony 5.* project myself and being new to the framework Your answer definitely helped.

Comment: An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar.

Answer (score 6):

As the response is in a comment, i repeat it :

Did you try the URL http://www.elora.dev/index.php/_wdt/ ? I had a similar problem because the URL rewriting was wrong. – [A.L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257664/a-l)

That's it !

1. /index.php doesn't have any issue with the debug toolbar
2. /index.php/lucky/number works

Thank's a lot [A.L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257664/a-l)

Answer (score 4):

Il sounds like a cache write issue. The profiler/debug toolbar crash because debug data is written to cache folder. Your application is probably running fine in `prod` environment.

To see if that's your issue, try running `chmod -R 777 var/cache`, and try again.

The "better fix" depend on your OS. Feel free to add some more information to answer precisely, otherwise you can have a look at Symfony related documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/setup/file_permissions.html) (outdated link on purpose, they removed it from SF4 doc).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i've already done the chmod 777 on var/cache, and the setfacl didn't change anything.
My application runs in `dev` environment.

Comment: As I said, I've noticed that the cache for the profiler is in that directory : var/cache/dev/profiler/03/74/ and is named 177403

So there's not any cache write issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and these solutions didn't help. In my case it was a much simpler problem. I upgraded symfony from 4.2 to 4.3, but not the other packages (including the web profiler). Whoops! Check the version of web profiler in composer.json.

[Symfony update from 4.2 to 4.3 caused Web Profiler to break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432536/symfony-update-from-4-2-to-4-3-caused-web-profiler-to-break)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can have a route in your controllers that catches `/_wdt/125121`, something like this:

```
@Route("/{_locale}/{courseSlug}", name="learning_course")
```

The requests for web `debug` toolbar will be `routed` here instead of the correct controller.

Use `route requirements` or fix your routes.

Answer (score 1):

As a small addition to previous answers if this happens to someone in general while the toolbar did indeed work before:

this can also be caused by unlucky renamings that one might have sloppily done via a *replace all*.

In this case it might even be sufficient to just issue:

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Then you probably got something else going on as well. Did you check the possible causes from previous answers as well? Furthermore, you might wanna cache-bust your browser as "hard" as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Other possible reasons of suddenly getting the error message

> "An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar."

- Your **log files** got too big
- Your system is busy (like an endless loop or max memory was reached etc.)

What I did and what resolved it in my case:

- Restart vagrant (if you are running it in vagrant of course)
- Delete all the log files (especially your dev.log)

  ```
  rm -rf var/logs
  ```
- Clear the cache

  ```
  bin/console cache:clear

  # OR if cache got corrupted
  rm -rf var/cache
  ```

This is when the web debug toolbar usually showed but suddenly stopped showing

Answer (score 0):

I had the error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("nb_errors") on a string variable

Upgrading to Symfony from 4.2 to 4.3 solved my problem

see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32018

Comment: How is this related to the given question? Looks like a completely different error

Comment: the error I pointed, when solved, make the error "An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar" disappeared